# remove Cache from files failed

Tags: ios, caching, memory

I am trying to release cache from files by calling this method :

```
    -(void)removeCacheFromFiles
    {
        NSFileManager *filemgr;

        filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error=nil;
        if ([filemgr removeItemAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] error: &error]  == YES)
            NSLog (@"Remove successful");
        else
            NSLog (@"Remove failed");
            NSLog(@"error %@",error);

        [filemgr createDirectoryAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
```

But I get "Remove failed" every time.

I tried this as well and get the same result:

```
    -(void)removeCacheFromFiles
    {
        NSFileManager *filemgr;

        filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSArray *cachePathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *cachePath = [cachePathList objectAtIndex:0];
        NSError *error=nil;
        if ([filemgr removeItemAtPath:cachePath error: &error]  == YES)
            NSLog (@"Remove successful");
        else
            NSLog (@"Remove failed");

        NSLog(@"error %@");
        [filemgr createDirectoryAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
```

Also where should this remove caching be down ? Is it a good practise to call it in ViewDidDisappear or in ViewDidAppear so that the cache is cleared when the view controller is called the second time ?

The error in the NSLog says :

error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“Caches” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x15fac9a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1795C59B-185F-4607-8682-004CDF3CDED7/Library/Caches, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
)}